# Major product formed when HBr is added to 1-phenyl but-2-ene

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, c-c-addition

Addition of $\ce{HBr}$ to $\ce{Ph-CH2-CH=CH-CH3}$ possibly yields two products:

- $\ce{Ph-CH2-CH2-CHBr-CH3}$ or
- $\ce{Ph-CH2-CHBr-CH2-CH3}$

Which one of them should possibly be the major product? Markovnikov's rule (incorrectly) predicts that both of them should be the major product because the double-bonded carbon atoms in the substrate contains equal number of hydrogen atoms.

Comment: That would depend on reaction parameters. Also you're missing a rearrangement product, quite possibly even more important than the two.

Comment: @Mithoron Could you please elaborate about which rearrangement product you're talking of?

Comment: Normal carbocation rearrangement when you got aromatic ring in neighbourhood. If you still don't get it check out your org. chem. book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phenyl groups are bulky and cause steric hindrance.

This makes the $\ce{Br^-}$ nucleophile have an easier time targeting the carbon atom in the double bond that's closer from the right side of the reactant molecule.

On the other hand, $\ce{H^+}$ is small enough to bypass said steric hindrance.

Therefore, the first product is more likely to form.